# Отличить ссылки на статью от других

Tags: python, url

У меня есть список новостных сайтов

```
[
'ria.ru',
'www.rbc.ru',
'lenta.ru',
'news.rambler.ru',
'kp.ru',
'iz.ru',
'www.gazeta.ru',
'vesti.ru',
'www.mk.ru',
'news.ngs.ru',
'russian.rt.com',
'life.ru',
'ren.tv',
'smi2.ru',
'kommersant.ru',
'svpressa.ru',
'tass.ru',
'cosmo.ru',
'lentainform.com',
'ura.ru',
'echo.msk.ru',
'vz.ru',
'www.aif.ru',
'dni.ru',
'www.ridus.ru',
'E1.RU',
'ridus.ru',
'rg.ru',
'tsargrad.tv',
'eg.ru',
 ]
```

Из них мне нужно взять только ссылки на статьи. Я использую find_all("a"), и пропускаю через цикл. Но проблема в том, что я должен отфильтровать настоящие ссылки на статью от других. Есть идеи как это реализовать?

Comment: Что такое "ссылки на статьи" и чем они отличаются от прочих ссылок? Приведите пример в вопросе (кнопочка "править")

Comment: Думаю, что для каждого сайта отдельно придётся формировать шаблон "различения" ссылок. Вряд ли все эти новостные сайты договаривались о едином шаблоне ссылок для облегчения работы роботам-парсерам...

Comment: ссылка на статью - новостная статья, где содержится новость. Остальное - ссылка на регистрацию, ссылка на "Похожее", или вообще на другой сайт.